# Dialog crashes - IllegalStateException

Tags: android, dialog, crash

can you maybe help me with this error.
I checked all Dialogs but I cannot find the error. A user reported this error to me but I do not know when it occurs.

The Logcat:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3435)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3306)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3282)
>   at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:432)
>   at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:260)
>   at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:337)
>   at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:357)
>   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:261)
>   at com.app.xxxxx.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:936)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17962)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

The error was reported with this device: Samsung Galaxy S4 (jflte)
I tried the app with a Galaxy S2. And never got this error. 
Do you have any idea how I can simulate the error? The line numbers unfortunately do not match to my app.

This seems to cause the error:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.addView(textView);
layout.addView(progressBar);
alert.setView(layout);
```

But I do not get the error with my device. So what can I do?

Comment: I think it is too long. Which part would be interesting for you? The Dialogs have always the same structure.

Comment: the dialog part the one that causes the crash

Comment: added some code. Hope that this will help.

Comment: can you show where alert is initialized?

Comment: Here: findViewById(R.id.getLog).setOnClickListener(             new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                  final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);

Comment: @JavaForAndroid : where you are adding Height and Width for layout LinearLayout ?

Comment: I do not add it. Is that necessary? It works without it on my device.